# how to sort a flexigrid using Selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Following is my code. When I run this, I get the list of data from a flexigrid, Once I get the data, how do I sort it in Ascending/descending order?

```java
package Experiments;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class getdatafromawebtable {
  static FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  String BaseURL = "https://qa.example.com/";
  int iwait = 3000;

  @Test
  public void sorting() throws Exception {
    driver.get(BaseURL);
    driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).sendKeys("username");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("pswd");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='input']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).click();

    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//descendant::table[4]"));

    List rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    int row_count = rows.size();
    System.out.println("Total rows is " + row_count);
    IteratorI1 = rows.iterator();

    while(I1.hasNext()){
      WebElement data = I1.next();

      List columns= data.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
      Iterator I2=columns.iterator();
      while(I2.hasNext()){
        WebElement text=I2.next();
        String columndata=text.getText();
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(columndata);
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      System.out.println("");
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This is a basic programming question about sorting Strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your columns list contains WebElements which have the `value` property.
You'll have to use a sorting algorithm that works on these values, to get the elements in the order you want.

I'm no Java expert, but see if you can use a custom Comparator, [here's a starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property).

If not, then you might write a simple algorithm yourself, [like this example](http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/bubble-sort/).

Answer (score 0):

You want to store the values in some sort of data structure, like a list or an array. Then, once you have the values, you can perform a sort on them. For example, you can call Arrays.sort(theArray).

More information about sorting: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/sorting_arrays.html